# Mysql problem ,cant resolve it, cant somebody help, i using java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, connection

Yoo coderrs, have problem connect and write table to my online free database. Problem is here`Unable to create requested service` and `Unable to make JDBC Connection`

```
"C:\Users\myhome\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56594:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\untitled\jpa\target\classes;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.3.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.11.20\byte-buddy-1.11.20.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.28\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar" sk.hibernate.App
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: sk.hibernate]
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.3.Final
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [mysql://****************:******************@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix]
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=ujfnz0sxud23qruy}
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
jan 28, 2022 10:05:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at sk.hibernate.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [mysql://ujfnz0sxud23qruy:lqoN4PMPxWAAUjNEKuv8@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
```

**1class**
package sk.hibernate;

```
import sk.hibernate.model.Message;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ){


        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sk.hibernate");

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(new Message("Prva sprava"));
        entityManager.persist(new Message("Druha sprava"));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();


    }
}
```

**2.class**

```
package sk.hibernate.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity

public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   // @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
   // @Column(name = "MESSAGE")

    private String message;

    private Date CREATE_DATE;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getCREATE_DATE() {
        return CREATE_DATE;
    }

    public void setCREATE_DATE(Date CREATE_DATE) {
        this.CREATE_DATE = CREATE_DATE;
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="sk.hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>sk.hibernate.model.Message</class>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="mysql://*****************:************************@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>

            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name = "hibernate.format_sql" value = "true" />
            <!--<property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update" />-->

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sk.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jpa</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>


    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project
```

> 

```
*MYSQL_ADDON_DB="bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix"
MYSQL_ADDON_HOST="bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com"
MYSQL_ADDON_PASSWORD="***"
MYSQL_ADDON_PORT="3306"
MYSQL_ADDON_URI="mysql://******************:***********************@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix"
MYSQL_ADDON_USER="****"
MYSQL_ADDON_VERSION="8.0"*
```

Comment: That JDBC URL looks odd. It should start with `jdbc:`

Comment: Please make sure that ujfnz0sxud*** and lqoN4PMPxWAAU*** are not your actual username and password. If they are: delete this question (everyone can see your edits) and change them. If you decide to ask the question again, remove those information from the URI.

Comment: y but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just accessed your database with the following URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://******************:******************@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix
```

(I masked the credentials). So you missed the prefix "jdbc:"

You should quickly change your username and password now. You don't want all of The Internet to have access, do you? I think someone might have renamed one of your tables...

Oh, and say hi to Patrik Severín for me, will you? ;-)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes there was problem :D, patrik is not me, is guy what i buy PC so i hope is not angry now:D. btw still doesnt work  `Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized`   and  `Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] `  and  ` Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set ` .

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=54133:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\untitled\jpa\target\classes;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.4.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.7\byte-buddy-1.12.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.28\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" sk.hibernate.App
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: sk.jpa]
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://ujf***ud23qruy:lqoN4PMP**8@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix]
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=ujfnz0sxud23qruy}
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
jan 29, 2022 10:39:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
jan 29, 2022 10:39:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at sk.hibernate.App.main(App.java:15)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at sk.hibernate.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).